# How can use .done jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As title, I use .done in my code but it is not working.

```js
get_widget_content('advanced_search').done(function(alert(1)));

function get_widget_content(widget) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + 'task/widget_content',
    data: "task_id=" + taskId + "&project_id=" + proId + "&widget=" + widget + "&tp_id=" + tpId,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#' + widget).html(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

and when I run. Browser said .done is not function.

Comment: Use this `$.ajax({}).done();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what your function returns:

```
function get_widget_content(widget) {
  // ...
  return false;
}
```

Then you try to call `.done()` on the returned value:

```
get_widget_content('advanced_search').done(function(alert(1)));
```

`false` is a boolean value.  It doesn't have a `.done()` function.

Either call `done()` on the AJAX call:

```
function get_widget_content(widget) {
  $.ajax({ /* ... */ }).done(function () { /* ... */ });
  return false;
}
```

or return the AJAX call and then you can call `.done()` on the return value:

```
get_widget_content('advanced_search').done(function() { /* ... */ }));
function get_widget_content(widget) {
  return $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
}
```

**Also:** note the typo in how you were calling it.  You had this:

```
function(alert(1))
```

which is a syntax error.  It should be this:

```
function(){alert(1);}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David. I have a confusion when I call alert. However, thank for your help. my case was solved. Have a good time

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
 get_widget_content('advanced_search').done(function(){alert(1)});
    function get_widget_content(widget){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : baseUrl+'task/widget_content',
                data: "task_id=" + taskId + "&project_id=" + proId + "&widget=" + widget + "&tp_id=" + tpId,
                success: function(data){  $('#'+widget).html(data);  }
            });
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
get_widget_content('advanced_search');
    function get_widget_content(widget){
            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url : baseUrl+'task/widget_content',
                            data: "task_id=" + taskId + "&project_id=" + proId + "&widget=" + widget + "&tp_id=" + tpId,
                            success: function(data){  $('#'+widget).html(data);  }
            }).done(function(alert(1)));
            return false;
    }
```